# Functions in Javascript using hover fade and fancybox

Tags: javascript, function, variables, dreamweaver

Currently the code below shows my image as grayscale and when hovered over--it shows in color. I need to add one more function to the image. When hovered over it needs to become a link to a Fancybox gallery. I am unsure how to code that. Notes: The list tag has the gray version and color version of the thumbnail. The section tag has the actual full size version that I want to link to.

This is the link to my full (under construction) site.

```
<!--gray to color on hover code--> 

<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("img.waldengray").hover(
        function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, "slow");
        },
        function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, "slow");
    });
});

</script>

<!--generic fancybox code-->

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.fancybox-thumbs').fancybox({
                prevEffect : 'none',
                nextEffect : 'none',

                closeBtn  : false,
                arrows    : false,
                nextClick : true,

                helpers : {
                    thumbs : {
                        width  : 50,
                        height : 50
                    }
                }
            });
});
</script>


<body>



<!--gray and color thumbnails-->
<ul>

<li><img src="images/waldengray.png" alt="waldengray" width="362" height="105" `class="waldengray" id="waldengray"></li>`
<li><img src="images/waldencolor.png" alt="waldencolor" width="362" height="105" class="waldencolor" id="waldencolor"></li>
</div>

</ul>


<!--full size image-->        
<section>
    <p><a class="fancybox-walden" data-fancybox-group="walden" href="images/waldenlrg.png"><img src="images/waldenlrg.png" alt="" /></a></p>
</section>












</div><!--wrapper-->


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about your question?

Comment: I have updated it :) Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Well go for refactoring by creating a a single function variable and reusing it:

```
var getAnimFn = function(config) {
       return function() {
          $(this).stop().animate(config, "slow");
       }
};
```

and then call it at required places as:

```
getAnimFn({"opacity": "0"});
getAnimFn({"opacity": "1"});
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, use a class for all the img's you need to animate, so just one call to hover is needed.

```
    $(".THE_CLASS").hover(
        function() {
            $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, "slow");
        },
        function() {
            $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, "slow");
        }
    );
```